# Add a text in Woocommerce order received page after the billing address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I would like to know on how to add text at woocommerce order-received page after the billing address at the bottom?

Is there any hook I can used? 
Or any other way can accomplished this?

Comment: You need to explain a little more. Also, please try to add some code or what you tried to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this custom hooked function in **`woocommerce_thankyou`** action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_content_thankyou', 10, 1 );
function custom_content_thankyou( $order_id ) {

    echo '<p>'. __('My custom text').'</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works…

Comment: Your solution did work! Thanks for your awesome support! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add action hooks inside your (child) theme or a plugin. Expanding @LoicTheAztec's answer:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_content_thankyou', 10, 1 );

function custom_content_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    echo '<p>'. __('My custom text').'</p>';
}
```

Here are [more actions](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/thankyou.php) that you can use, that are unfortunately not (yet?) mentioned in the [official WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook Reference documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html):

1. `woocommerce_before_thankyou`
2. `woocommerce_thankyou_{payment_method}` (dynamic)
3. `woocommerce_thankyou`

There are times when you need the order details and shipping method. To get the order details you can use `$order = new WC_Order($order_id);`. For example:

```php
function produkindo_before_thankyou($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    // Iterating through order shipping items
    foreach( $order->get_items( 'shipping' ) as $item_id => $shipping_item_obj ){
        // $order_item_name             = $shipping_item_obj->get_name();
        // $order_item_type             = $shipping_item_obj->get_type();
        // "Prahu-Hub" or "Prahu - Hub"
        $shipping_method_title       = $shipping_item_obj->get_method_title();
        $shipping_method_id          = $shipping_item_obj->get_method_id(); // The method ID
        $shipping_method_instance_id = $shipping_item_obj->get_instance_id(); // The instance ID
        // $shipping_method_total       = $shipping_item_obj->get_total();
        // $shipping_method_total_tax   = $shipping_item_obj->get_total_tax();
        // $shipping_method_taxes       = $shipping_item_obj->get_taxes();
        break;
    }
    if (preg_match('/^Prahu/i', $shipping_method_title)) {
        ?>
        <div class="prahu-hub-thankyou">
            Silakan melanjutkan pemesanan pengiriman untuk barang yang Anda beli di <a target="_blank" href="https://prahu-hub.com/home/pencarian"><strong>Prahu–Hub</strong></a>.
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_thankyou', 'produkindo_before_thankyou');
```